# How to automatically call a method when Session["something"] throws a NullReferenceException?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am going to be using `Session["firmaid"]` quite alot in my application. This value is set when someone logs in to my system.

If something happens, and this value is lost from the Session, i would like to somehow have a global method that will get it, if it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

How can i do this?

Currently, my solution is to try and catch every time i use `Session["firmaid"]`, then execute the method that will put firmaid in the Session, if it throws an `Exception`.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of try/catching everytime you could wrap the access to the session in a strongly typed class and then access the session through this wrapper.

Or even write an extension method:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static string GetFirmaId(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        var firmaid = session["firmaid"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firmaid))
        {
            // TODO: call some method, take respective actions
        }      
        return firmaid;
    }
}
```

and then in your code instead of:

```
try
{
    var firmaid = Session["firmaid"];
    // TODO: do something with the result
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // TODO: call some method, take respective actions
}
```

use:

```
var firmaid = Session.GetFirmaId();
// TODO: do something with the result
```

Comment: VS cant find HttpSessionBase, and it doesnt know what to import. Do you mean HttpSessionStateBase ?

Comment: @Kenci, that's exactly what I meant: `HttpSessionStateBase`.

Comment: Did you put this class in a special namespace?

Comment: @Kenci, you can put it in any namespace you like. Just make sure to bring it into scope when you want to use it. It's the way extension methods work in .NET.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply write a static wrapper around this? Much more robust and more DRY:

```
public static int GetFirmaid() {
  if (HttpContext.Current.Session["firmaid"] == null) {
     //do something to fall back
  }
  return HttpContext.Current.Session["firmaid"]
}
```

You obviously would have to put this in a Class you can easily access and then call it through:

```
Class.GetFirmaid()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action filter which will ensure that Session["firmaid"] has a value:

```
public class SetFirmaIdAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var firmaId = Session["firmaid"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // pass filterContext if you need access to Request, Session etc.
            Session["firmaid"] = SetFirmaId(filterContext);
        }
   }

   private int SetFirmaId(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       // TODO: implement some logic
   }
}
```

`OnActionExecuting` will be called before action executes so you will already have `Session["firmaid"]` set when the action gets executed.

Once you implement this attribute you can put it on an action, controller or set it as global.