# How to get User.Identity working in a class outside of a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

After a user Logs in to the system, i need to put a variable in the Session. I am doing this with an extension method:

Login method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                    int id = this.HttpContext.GetFirmaId();
                    String username = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

                    //SessionExtensions.SetFirmaId(Session, model.UserName);

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                        {
                            RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Brugernavn eller password er forkert.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Extension method:

```
public static int GetFirmaId(this HttpContextBase context)
    {

        var firmaid = context.Session["firmaid"] as int?;

        if (firmaid == null)
        {
            // Hvis firmaid er røget ud af Session, skal den firmaid som tilhører brugeren hentes

            firmaid = SetFirmaId(context.Session, context.User.Identity.Name);

        }

        return (int)firmaid;
    }
```

The problem is that `context.User.Identity.Name` returns an empty string.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Where are you calling it?  Why don't you extend `HttpContextBase`?

Comment: Im calling it in a static class i use as a helper. How do i use HttpContextBase? It has Equals and ReferenceEquals methods.

Comment: Take it as a parameter instead of `HttpSessionStateBase`.

Comment: Does using the 'this' keyword in the method signature mean that i dont have to pass it as an parameter, when i call the method? Because it says that i have to. How do i pass a HttpContextBase parameter to the method?

Comment: If you use action filter to solve the session problem instead of extension method, you could get it form filter context: filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name Take a look at my answer for your session problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/8630059/576752

Comment: @frennky I will take a look in to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
public static int GetFirmaId(this HttpContextBase context)
        {

            var firmaid = context.Session["firmaid"] as int?;

            if (firmaid == null)
            {
                // Hvis firmaid er røget ud af Session, skal den firmaid som tilhører brugeren hentes

                firmaid = SetFirmaId(context.Session, context.User.Identity.Name);

            }

            return (int)firmaid;
        }
```

**UPDATE** - as per comment: use it just like `this.HttpContext.GetFirmaId()` from your controller.

Some useful links:

- [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx

**UPDATE 2** - as per comments:

The problem of being `User.Identity.Name` has no connection to the question - the answer above is what to do to access it in a class outside of a Controller.

AS the OP saw in the debugger it is even empty inside the controller in this specific case - I suspect that it is being accessed "too early" in the process so that it is indeed empty.

If you need help dealing with `AccountController` ask a new question.

Comment: From where would i be able to use HttpContext.Current.GetFirmaId() ? It doesnt show up in my Controller. When calling GetFirmaId from a Controller, VS says that it needs an argument.

Comment: @Kenci: `HttpContext.GetFirmaId()`.  (`HttpContext` is a property that returns an `HttpContextBase` instance)  You need to understand how extension methods work.

Comment: When i use this approach, context.User.Identity.Name is still empty. I am calling it from the built-in AccountController the way you described: this.HttpContext.GetFirmaId(); (after i log in)

Comment: @Kenci `context.User.Identity.Name` is technically allowed to be empty... and if in your case it shouldn't be empty then you need to provide more information/source code... otherwise I can only speculate which won't solve anything IMHO...

Comment: @Yahia Please take a look at my updated question, with your approach

Comment: @Kenci What does the line `String username = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;` show in the debugger ? I would be surprised if it were not empty!

Comment: @Yahia String username = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is empty in the debugger

Comment: @Kenci Then the problem has no connection to your question - the answer above is what to do to access it in a class outside of a Controller. AS you yourself saw in the debugger it is even empty inside the controller in your specific case - I suspect that you are accessing it "too early" in the process so that it is indeed empty. If you need help dealing with `AccountController` ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) If you would like to edit your answer with your last comment, i would be happy to give you a checkmark.

Comment: @Kenci addeded an UPDATE 2 to my answer.